# Factorizing polynomials: How to calculate $g_{(X)}\in F_{q}[x]$ if we have $f_{(x)} = g_{(x)}^p$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

How do I calculate $g_{(X)}\in F_{q}[x]$ if we have $f_{(x)} = g_{(x)}^p$ and $p$ is the characteristic of the field $F$?

This problem arises from the factorization of a polynomial into irreducible polynomials. In case we have $f_{(x)}={g_{(x)}^ p}$, then 
$$GCD(f_{(x)},f'_{(x)})=f_{(x)}$$

because $f'_{(x)}=0. $ In this case, how can we have the polynomial whose irreducible polynomials is of degree 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself.

In every $F[x]$ we have $f_{(x)}^p=f_{(x^p)}$ where p is the characteristic of the field. Hence, 
$$g_{(x)}=f_{(x^{1/p})}$$

Now we can compute that easily.